# OpenFileDialog class does not have a copy-constructor error

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I use c++\cli, and want to show some dialog.

The code is:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
```

That should be simple, but I have compiler error:

```
error C3673: 'System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog' : class does not have a copy-constructor
```

How can I overcome this situation and use a dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI `gcnew` returns a reference.

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
```

Note the `^`

Alternatively;

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;
```

Will create it using "stack semantics", http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx.